# Efficient SELECT query to find records within a month

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MySQL DB table with multiple date type fields. I need to do different SELECT queries on this table but I am not sure which way is the best to find records from the same month.

I know I can do the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE MONTH(somedate) = 5
   AND YEAR(somedate) = 2015
```

But I keep reading that isn't efficient and that I should go with using actual dates, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE somedate BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31'
```

However, all I would have is the month and the year as variables coming in from PHP. How do I easily and quickly calculate the last day of the month if I go with second option?

Comment: I'm finding `between` to be slower than `month/year`, and `like`, on my db. Month/year = `Showing rows 0 - 29 (77 total, Query took 0.0825 sec)`. Between = `Showing rows 0 - 29 (77 total, Query took 0.1059 sec)`. Like = `Showing rows 0 - 29 (77 total, Query took 0.0815 sec)`. This is on a 7k row table. This thread points in the other direction though. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96245/mysql-date-field-filter-by-like-vs-month

Comment: MySQL can make effective use of an index with leading column of `somedate`. If you don't have an index like that, then you can create one e.g. `CREATE INDEX ON table (somedate)`.  As long as the query is returning less than 10% of the rows in the table, the index will make the query much faster. With the functions wrapped around the somedate column, MySQL has to evaluate those functions on every row in the table.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan. For performance comparisons, make sure that the query results aren't being returned from the query cache. There's several ways to do that, e.g.`SQL_NO_CACHE` hit, include user defined variable in the query, disable the query cache, etc.  (We actually have our MySQL servers configured to cache *only* queries that that include the `SQL_CACHE` hint, so we control what queries can be cached, and prevent results from being flushed out by queries we don't need cached.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't calculate the last day of the month. Calculate the first day of the next month instead.

Your query can be like this

```
WHERE t.mydatetimecol >= '2015-05-01'
  AND t.mydatetimecol  < '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Note that we're doing a **less than** comparison, not a "less than or equal to"... this is very convenient for comparing TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns, which can include a time portion.

Note that a `BETWEEN` comparison is a "less than or equal to". To get a comparison equivalent to the query above, we'd need to do

```
WHERE t.mydatetimecol
      BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL -1 SECOND
```

(This assumes that the resolution of `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` is down to a second. In other databases, such as SQL Server, the resolution is finer than a second, so there we'd have the potential of missing a row with value of '2015-05-31 23:59:59.997'. We don't have a problem like that with the less than the first day of the next month comparison... `< '2015-06-01'`

No need to do the month or date math yourself, let MySQL do it for you. If you muck with adding 1 to the month, you have to handle the rollover from December to January, and increment the year.  MySQL has all that already builtin.

Answer (score 3):

`date('t', strtotime("$year-$month-01"))` will give days in the month

Comment: The "how to do" question for this specific task was asked at the end though. I think BETWEEN would be a better performer, and may elaborate on that later if someone else doesn't get to it first.